# Creating a SSMS add-in from VS2010

Tags: .net, add-in, ssms

I am trying to create an add-in by using the article below 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2008/07/28/how-to-create-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx
I know this article is a bit outdated but i managed to get as far as this article again 
http://jcooney.net/post/2007/11/26/The-Black-Art-of-Writing-a-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-2005-Add-In.aspx
here once i reached when the part adding the external program to run upon debug i was met with this nasty error
[image]

is there any good article to show how to do the add-in using the VS2010 for the SMSS2008r2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a problem starting the debug ?
You have to specify SSMS without any parameters - it must be enough.
But I have "bad news" for you: I have also developed an add-in and during development the problem that I have faced was:
you can debug SSMS2008 Add-In only from VS2008 (full or express) and you can defbug
SSMS2012 add-in only from VS2010
If you "cross" versions, you have to put a message box in your add-in and then attach to process.
Check my add-in - ssmsboost - maybe you will not need to write your own :) New feature requests are welcome. Also check ssms tools pack - it is also very popular one.

Comment: tks for the reply so much was wondering how u did yours and yes i did download the ssms tool pack but there is no source code for that right?

Comment: right - no sources :) - if you need some samples of simple add-ins - check ssmsaddins.codeplex.com - there are several add-ins. But remember what I wrote about debugging - to avoid problems do not mix VS2008 with SSMS2012 and vice-versa. I think that it lies in different versions of DTE. And - maybe consider saving your time and better write me what feature you need - I will say you if we can implement it.

Comment: Well actaully i want to implement a query managment system...like save ur queries in the application and when the button is pressed it is automatically copied over to the opened query window..if not opened show a message box...i know how to make the querys store in a xml format but the add-in part i am not sure

Comment: I was also thinking of doing this as a standalone application like a WPF application and then when the button is pressed it is automatically copied over to the opened query window in the SSMS..if not opened show a message box

Comment: SSMS itself has template management, ssms tools pack has something like "restore last session". If it does not suit you - maybe describe it exactly. It might overfill the topic here - if you want - you can add proposal in our "new features" thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ssmsboost

Comment: Wow u have a group..ok gr8t i will join this group..right now at work..will do this at the end of the day..tks so much for your help..but really hope there is a tutorial for making a add-in for the ssms08r2 using the vs2008 (i have this as well)